# Use Sinatra to serve php files

Tags: php, ruby, sinatra

I am using Sinatra to design a web interface for some research we are doing. However, I also want to be able to use phpMyAdmin for database administration. Is there any way to get Sinatra to serve up php? I know that it can be done with some tweaks to Apache, but since I do not control our setup, I was hoping to be able to do it from within Sinatra.

The server I'll be working on is Windows (don't know what version), has Ruby 1.9.2, PHP 5.3.5, and Apache 2.2, and there are no other web facing or database related projects on it.

My goal is to be be able to access it like this:

`researchserveraddress/app/admin/index.php`
where

`researchserveraddress/app/` would be the main page of our app (served by Sinatra).

I'm sorry if I'm unclear, I do not have very much experience with servers and deploying an app, so far, everything I have done has been locally.

Comment: This may be of use: https://github.com/creationix/rack-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [rack-legacy](https://github.com/eric1234/rack-legacy/wiki), which allows Sinatra to serve PHP files. It simply uses `php-cgi` to run the scripts. For example, put phpMyAdmin under directory `admin` and put something along these lines to `config.ru`:

```
require 'app'

map "/admin" do
    use Rack::Legacy::Php, 'admin'
    use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/'], :root => 'admin'
    run lambda{|env| [200, {'Content-type' => 'text/plain'}, 'OK']}
end

map "/" do
    run Sinatra::Application
end
```

(If you're not familiar with using `config.ru` with your Sinatra app, see [this part of Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Using%20a%20Classic%20Style%20Application%20with%20a%20config.ru)).

I'd suggest to configure Apache instead if possible. It strikes me as a cleaner solution and it would be also more efficient, but that's probably not a problem if you're only using it for phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra can't interpret the PHP files so any embedded variables will be left unprocessed.

You COULD use Sinatra to redirect the requests to the appropriate PHP page, which is then handled in the normal fashion by the PHP processor.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to put PHP files into the public folder? (I do not know).